# Good QT or KDE program with source to use as a non-trivial example

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

The QT dev kit comes with some good examples of how to code features via trivial apps, but nothing comes close to showing how to structure a complex program in QT.  What, if anything, should be global, etc?  Pitfalls in designing your classes that would turn out to need a lot of eventual refactoring?

I'm sure there are plenty of open source KDE apps that would serve nicely, so I guess my question is what't the minimal amount of source code I'd need to download and set up in order to work with, say, Dolphin as a sample app?  If the answer is 'all of KDE', then I guess this isn't practical (unless downloading and building all of KDE from source is easy enough to make that practical).

Any suggestions?  Personally, I'm looking to build a browser-like app, but much simpler.  So for an example to follow, something that handles sockets and multiple tabbed viewports would be nice.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I posted an answer because it was easier than a comment, but you should read [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) way you can't ask for recommendation on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The main advice regarding Qt itself is I would give is to try to spend as much effort as possible in learning to use Qt's Model View Delegate functionality. It can be a lot of work to wrap your head around, but once you get there, you can do very powerful things with it. Another relatively tricky topic you will want to invest learning resources in is memory management and how Qt facilitates (and doesn't facilitate) it.

One of the most confusing things to me was though that when your model is very complex, you might not want to have your core model class be a Qt model at all. Instead, I nowadays see Qt models as something that primarily provide data to views. If your model is very complex, you might want to use your actual, more complex model as a data source for the Qt model class (an QAbstractItemModel derivative), which in turn attaches to the UI view.

Also, Qt documentation is your friend. Qt is a wide framework and contains LOTS of useful functionality. I love the data structures in their ease of use, for example: QHash, QList, etc.

Project scaffolding features for beginners, for different project types in Qt Creator might indeed be useful. For now, the Qt Examples actually are quite good ones, and contain lots of good practices. You just need to pick and choose what you need.

I have been developing our Qt desktop [app family](http://scanrobot.fi/forceproof-materials-testing/) for five years now. Our directory structure is quite unorthodox - the main thing is that we have lib/ under which we have grouped different related functionality in subdirectories. The thinking goes, if something is in lib, it is general-purpose and atomic enough to be used in several of the actual desktop applications in our software family.

Your question seems more general level than Qt. It is difficult to tell if you are looking for a more general level computer science education. Globals in general should be avoided, sure. OTOH, we do have a constants.h and other immutable configuration data that is global-like, since it is needed in many places. This adds state though, so it can have unpredictable consequences if you don't do it carefully.

You could look for directory structures in places like this, though I don't really follow this advice myself. http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/

Unless you are planning to contribute directly to KDE, I would advice against learning KDE way of doing things. Not necessarily because they are doing things badly, but because it is a world of its own - the best practice for KDE development might not be the best practice for a stand-alone Qt app. (Disclaimer: I, as a UI developer, don't actually *like* KDE, so I do not know the project very well - aside from the fact that it indeed seems a bit monolithic to the outsider.)

So I wonder if something like [Qupzilla](http://www.qupzilla.com) would fit the bill for you? (Found via [qt-apps](http://qt-apps.org/).)

HTH.